# RedHat Enterprise 7.2 init.d runlevel 0 script cannot find file in /home directory

Tags: linux, redhat, reboot, init.d

I have an etc/init.d script that tries to call a shell script in a /home/myuser directory. One shell script for startup, another shell script for shutdown.

The start script gets called just fine ( from rc3.d/S99cslink , rc5.d/S99cslink ) but when I try to call the stop script ( from rc0.d/K01cslink ) I get the message that /home/myuser/bin/stop_service.sh cannot be found.

/etc/rc.d/init.d/cslink: line 42: /home/myuser/bin/stop_service.sh: No such file or directory

I verified that at the point in time when I am trying to run /home/myuser/bin/stop_service.sh , /home/myuser is unavailable (an ls -l /home/myuser >/tmp/mylog.log 2>&1 from inside the init.d script shows the error

ls: cannot access /home/myuser: No such file or directory

Both the start) script and the stop) script in init.d are run with runuser -l myuser, so I don't think it's a permissions problem.

Why would /home/myuser be unavailab.e, and can I run my script at a different point in time when /home/myuser is still available?

All the answers I see through searching are saying that I should check for Windows-style carriage returns in my stop_service.sh script, but I have checked and that's not the issue here.

Comment: Run levels http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/run-levels-intro.html /home/ : Definitely in run level 3, may be run level 2?

Comment: Since RHEL 7 using systemd instead of init I would recommend to crate a service file. RHEL mostly use home folder on different partition maybe systemd unmount it before the scripts in rc0.d run, Or its because your home folder only avaliable at runlevel 2,3,4 and 5. runlevel 0,1 and 6 only have root user.